# Ставится ли запятая: "Согласно требованиям ..., решение требует ..."?

Tags: пунктуация

Добрый день. Ставится ли запятая в предложении: "Согласно требованиям Министерства, решение данного вопроса требует..."?

Answer (score 3):

Запятую можно не ставить. Практика показывает, что в начале предложения конструкция с предлогом *согласно* обычно не выделяется запятой. 
Подробно можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_693).

Comment: Смысловая нагрузка (что и является условием обособления) такого оборота повышается 
при его расположении в начале предложения

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в подобных конструкциях опциональна. Здесь, думаю лучше без неё. А вообще чем больше осложнена фраза всякими обособленными конструкциями и оборотами, тем больше оснований запятую эту поставить.

Answer (score 1):

В конкретном контексте запятая без надобности

Answer (score 1):

Вообще-то, слова "согласно требованию Министерства" - это вполне классическая вводная конструкция, означающая источник сообщения, поэтому запятая нужна.